# PHP foreach giving wrong result

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach, while-loop

I've searched for this for quite a while now and I cannot figure out why my code isn't working how it appears. I'm not sure if I'm having a block or anything but here goes:

```
$start = 1;
$sstart = strval($start);
$scan = scandir('upload');
$result = null;
while($result==null)
    {
        foreach($scan as $value)
        {
            if(strpos($value,$start) == false)
                {
                    $result = $start;
                    break 2;
                }
            else
                {
                    $start = $start + 1;
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

Essentially, I want to scan my directory `'upload'` for any files with the number held in `$start`. If this value ISN'T found, then `$result` takes the value of `$start` and the `while()` loop ends. Otherwise I increment `$start` and proceed to check every file in the directory again.

Now I have a very similar function like this running on another page that works flawlessly. However this always seems to stop at 1.

There is DEFINITELY a file in my upload folder called `showreel1.wmv` and it definitely scans this. (Have echo'd the scandir array) However, it never seems to switch to the `else` block but carries on setting `$result` as if it never found the value '1'.

I have also tried using `$sstart` in the `strpos()` function and it has no effect, this of course changes the value of `$start` into a string.

Can you guys shed any light on this for me please?

Comment: what's the end result you want?

Comment: if(strpos($value,$start) === false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood what you're trying to do, try with this:

```
while($result === null)
{
    $found = false;
    foreach($scan as $value)
    {
        if(strpos($value,$start) !== false)
        {
            $found = true;
            $start = $start + 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(!$found)
    {
        $result = $start;
        break;
    }
}
```

By the way, you should learn how to use `===` operator, it's essential to correctly use `strpos()`

Comment: I had to edit this slightly but yeah this worked. Thanks Uby!

Answer (score 1):

strpos returns 0 if the haystack begins with the needle you're searching for

This line will return a false positive (ie, it'll tell you it doesn't contain the string even if it actually starts with the string)

```
if(strpos($value,$start) == false)
```

You need to use the `===` operator to match exactly false

```
 if(strpos($value,$start) === false)
```

Comment: I am getting the same result. It's as if id doesn't see the '1' in showreel1.wmv.

Everytime I go through this it is re-uploading showreel1.wmv so I know it is there!

Comment: well, is showreel1.wmv the only file in the folder? If not, it'll fail on the first file it encounters, unless it happens to be the first file listed.

Comment: No there are a few files in the directory, I am aiming to scan all of them and if none of them contain '1' then it moves to uploading, otherwise if it DOES find '1' then it moves to looking for '2' in the files.

Comment: Then @uby's answer is the way to go. Your logic is flawed, unless the first file contains a 1 it's going to break the loop every time without looking at any other files.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of scandir, you can also use the [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php). You can skip the . and .. much more easily, and you will also get the basepath, subpath etc. While it's not your problem, it might ease your development.

Answer (score 0):

You are always breaking out of the foreach statement, so you are only checking the first file in the directory. I guess the firstfile in the directory has a name with a number in it, else it would be an eternal loop.

```
while($result==null)
{
  foreach($scan as $value)
  {
    if(strpos($value,$start) == false)
    {
      $result = $start;
      break 2; //end the while loop
    }
    else
    {
        $start = $start + 1;
        break; //end the foreach, but result = null so start with a new foreach
    }
  }
}
```

I guess you want to find the lowest number not in any file. In that case I would use

```
$start = 0; //start with zero because I increase it before the check
$result = null;
while($result==null)
{
  $start++;
  $found = false;
  foreach($scan as $value)
  {
    if(strpos($value,$start) !== false) {
      $found = true;
      break; //end the foreach
    }
  }

  if (!$found)
    $result = $start;
}
```